# Как выбирать куда сохранять между таблицами в базе данных?

Tags: python, sqlite

Ребят, такой вопрос, у меня есть class Users() и class Product(). В Users() я создаю пользователя, данные о нем записываются в словарь {'name_users':'Ivan', 'calories': 1800.0, 'protein': 170.0, 'fats': 67.0, 'carbohydrates': 230.0} и сохраняются в таблицы базы данных для users.
В Product() я создаю продукт и сохраняю его в таблице product в базе данных.
Есть еще class Base() которые отвечает за общение с базой данных и там есть метод который отвечает за добавление данных о пользователе в таблицу users:

```
    def set_add_base_person(self, base, result_kbju):
        lst = []
        lst.append(self.name)
        for i in result_kbju.values():
            lst.append(i)
        con = sql.connect(base)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name_users, calories, protein, fats, carbohydrates) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", lst)
        con.commit()
```

Не охото создавать отдельный метод который будет добавлять в базу данных информацию о продукте.
Как мне лучше оформить этот метод, чтобы он сохранял в базе данных в разные таблицы users или product, в зависимости от того добавляю я нового пользователя или новый продукт??
Можно ли просто передавать этому методу какой то флаг, и с помощью инструкции if и флага, уже выбирать таблицу??

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать отдельный интерфейс Formatter с методом SQLFormat, реализовать его в двух классах ProductFormatter и UserFormatter и передавать объекты этих классов в метод. Они должны преобразовывать объекты user и project в sql формат.